# Counting elements in tuple

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, tuples

I have a lot of ticket-dictionaries that all look like this:

```
{'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Intern', 
'ticket-closed': False, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 30, 17, 490990, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Important')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 30, 17, 490990, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 41, 52, 408334, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'developing')]}

{'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Intern', 
'ticket-closed': False, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 39, 34, 351329, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Important')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 39, 34, 351329, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new')}

{'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Intern', 
'ticket-closed': False, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Important')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 42, 49, 339349, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}
```

I want to make a pie chart in `matplotlib` to show how many tickets are 'new', 'developing' or 'closed', therefore I need to check the last value of `"status-events"` I've tried it like this but it doesn't work, my counters don't increment.

```
newCounter = 0
closedCounter = 0
developingCounter = 0


for (i,j) in OpenedDict.iteritems():
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'new':
        newCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'closed':
        closedCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'developing':
        developingCounter += 1
```

Comment: Replace those `if` branches with `print (j['status-events'][-1])` and see what it is.

Comment: Does that look like a string? Does that answer you question? :)

Comment: What is in `OpenedDict`? Is it a `dict`(-like object) where the values are the `dict`s you posted? Can you prepare a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @skyking: it's the dict in the example.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Which of them? None of them has the required structure, that's why I suggested a MCVE.

Comment: Yes, that's why it "doesn't work". Asking for an MCVE is completely fine. I just told you that because the OP posted the result of that print, and it was the dict from his example. Then he removed the comment. Honestly, feel free to downvote him...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Where did he post the result of that print? As far as I can see it should only raise exception if you use one of those `dict`s as `OpenedDict`. I think the lack of MCVE is risking to cause some serious misunderstanding here...

Comment: "Then he removed the comment."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're reading the wrong element to count, status-events is a list of tuples.

To trace why it's not being read correctly, try to print `j['status-events'][-1]` to the terminal to see what values you're comparing.  Right now, this will return a tuple.

If you only care about the last item in `status-events` list, you can just modify the script to be:

```
for (i,j) in OpenedDict.iteritems():
    if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'new':
        newCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'closed':
        closedCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1][-1] == 'developing':
        developingCounter += 1
```

Otherwise, if you want the values of every item in the list `status-events` you have to create another loop for it:

```
for (i,j) in OpenedDict.iteritems():
    for k in j['status-events']:
        if k[-1] == 'new':
            newCounter += 1
        if k[-1] == 'closed':
            closedCounter += 1
        if k[-1] == 'developing':
            developingCounter += 1
```

In addition to that, it seems like you have a missing bracket in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you need. It makes use of Python's `Counter` class to count each of the `status-events` types and then displays the collated information in a pie chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from collections import Counter

events = [
    {'origin': u'HW', 
    'department': u'Intern', 
    'ticket-closed': False, 
    'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 30, 17, 490990), u'Important')], 
    'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 30, 17, 490990), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 41, 52, 408334), u'developing')]},

    {'origin': u'HW', 
    'department': u'Intern', 
    'ticket-closed': False, 
    'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 39, 34, 351329), u'Important')], 
    'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 39, 34, 351329), u'new')]},

    {'origin': u'HW', 
    'department': u'Intern', 
    'ticket-closed': False, 
    'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331), u'Important')], 
    'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 42, 49, 339349), u'closed')]}]

event_types = Counter()

for event in events:
    for status in event['status-events']:
        event_types[status[1]] += 1

plt.pie(event_types.values(), labels=event_types.keys(), autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

This would display a pie chart as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `OpenedDict` is indeed one of the listed `dict`s, that is if a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would look something like:

```
OpenedDict = {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Intern', 
'ticket-closed': False, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Important')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 42, 49, 339349, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}

newCounter = 0
closedCounter = 0
developingCounter = 0

for (i,j) in OpenedDict.iteritems():
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'new':
        newCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'closed':
        closedCounter += 1
    if j['status-events'][-1]== 'developing':
        developingCounter += 1
```

Then you've got a problem because you're iterating the items and then investigate the values. `i` and `j` will for example take values like:

```
i = 'origin'
j = u'HW'

i = 'department'
j = u'Intern'

i = 'ticked-closed'
j = False
```

etc. You can't expect to find any 'status-events' in those values. Instead you would have to inspect such a dictionary directly instead. Something like:

```
OpenedDict = {'origin': u'HW', 
'department': u'Intern', 
'ticket-closed': False, 
'prio-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'Important')], 
'status-events': [(datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 49, 58, 454331, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'new'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 42, 49, 339349, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+02:00" 2:00:00>), u'closed')]}

newCounter = 0
closedCounter = 0
developingCounter = 0

if OpenedDict['status-events'][-1]== 'new':
    newCounter += 1
if OpenedDict['status-events'][-1]== 'closed':
    closedCounter += 1
if OpenedDict['status-events'][-1]== 'developing':
    developingCounter += 1
```